# Phone or router asks to sign in when connecting to WiFi

Tags: wireless-router, android

My phone keeps asking me to sign into my WiFi router. Almost every morning same goes for my wife's Pixel XL 1. Is this a phone issue or router issue. Forgetting the network doesn't help.

[image]

Comment: What page is shown when you actually open the "Sign-in" notification?

Comment: My pixel doesn't really take me to a sign in page, it in the settings app it redirects really fast. Not sure what it does, but it's blank and when it's done my WiFi icon goes back to normal.

Comment: Do you perhaps have internet connectivity issues? Does your ISP hijack DNS errors to serve error pages? That could lead to this incorrect behavior.

Comment: Every great once in a while I'll get isp error page for a domain that doesn't exist. Generally the speeds are good.

Comment: See that your ISP stops hijacking DNS errors and/or try using a different DNS server (Google, Cloudflare, Quad9, whatever).

Comment: Swapping an dns seems like an easy solution. I'll find a good one. Thank you!